# Unable to parse Google Assistant's Buffer response into String

Tags: node.js, string, buffer, google-assistant-sdk

I'm using Google Assistand SDK to query command to it, it's actually working perfectly, but in the query response it returns a conversationState as a Buffer, already tried many ways to parse the Buffer into a String but with no luck

Tried the example over here https://hackernoon.com/https-medium-com-amanhimself-converting-a-buffer-to-json-and-utf8-strings-in-nodejs-2150b1e3de57 that are similar to the one i found here on StackOverFlow

In the JSON Response i receive:

```
"conversationState":{"type":"Buffer","data":[10,38,67,35,53,100,57,53,53,53,53,51,45,48,48,48,48,45,50,53,97,49,45,57,51,98,54,45,50,52,48,53,56,56,54,100,51,56,53,48,18,231,1,75,106,57,90,101,110,100,74,86,109,49,117,88,49,70,79,83,88,112,66,84,107,86,73,77,109,70,119,89,108,86,51,87,108,74,76,90,85,112,81,100,110,82,97,98,69,49,89,87,68,78,116,76,86,74,54,82,49,70,66,81,85,70,69,81,86,90,108,97,50,78,82,77,108,82,87,101,107,112,51,81,85,70,66,81,85,69,52,114,79,71,103,54,81,86,54,86,119,111,85,67,65,69,83,69,68,65,119,77,68,65,119,77,68,100,104,78,71,82,106,90,71,81,120,79,68,85,83,80,49,108,54,100,48,108,87,98,87,53,102,85,85,53,74,101,107,70,79,82,85,103,121,89,88,66,105,86,88,100,97,85,107,116,108,83,108,66,50,100,70,112,115,84,86,104,89,77,50,48,116,85,110,112,72,85,85,70,66,81,85,82,66,86,109,86,114,89,49,69,121,86,70,90,54,83,110,100,66,81,85,70,66,81,89,111,66,67,103,106,51,55,75,45,66,54,100,121,108,50,66,85]}
```

What i do is this: As i receive an object with many parameters i only extract the conversationState and parse it to JSON

```
let conversationJson = JSON.stringify(conversationState);
```

Then i send it to the Buffer parser:

```
let bufferOriginal = Buffer.from(JSON.parse(conversationJson).data);
let buffer = Buffer.from(bufferOriginal);
```

and finally print it in console:

```
console.log(`BufferDataUTF: ${buffer.toString('utf8')}`);
```

so after doing what the example said i should receive a Buffer in format:

Buffer xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx xx

from de Json, but instead i receive:

&C#5d952c74-0000-21f7-a186-2405886e4e48�Kj9ZendJVm1uX1FOSXpjRmxNM2YwbS1WeFdGcFZRdmhaRUgyU3JiazBaUkFBQUFEQVZla2NRMlRWek53QUFBQUE4ieeg6QV6VwoUCAESEDAwMDAwMDdhNGRjZGQxODUSP1l6d0lWbW5fUU5JemNGbE0zZjBtLVZ4V0ZwVlF2aFpFSDJTcmJrMFpSQUFBQURBVmVrY1EyVFZ6TndBQUFBQYoBCgjczrqskvKl2BU

Any ideas what could be wrong?? thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat intentional. The [conversation_state](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/reference/rpc/google.assistant.embedded.v1alpha2#dialogstatein) value is a unique identifier that allows the Assistant to retain context for a given conversation on a device. This enables things like follow-up queries to work.

In the documentation it is listed as type `bytes`. It's an opaque, non-useful, string for your purposes. But in order to keep the context you need to track it and send it in every follow-on request.

Comment: so how can i get assistants response when i ask like "is my device on?", if i ask that over Google Assistant app it responds "device is on", i'm using assistand sdk with grpc

Comment: That would come from `AssistResponse.audio_out`

Comment: is not possible over text response? i'm talking with assistant over text

Comment: Text responses are supplemental, and are not guaranteed in every response.